# Object Required Error MS Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I'm stuck in this SQL statement in my VBA coding. I'm trying to complete an update query with an DLookUp but I may not have written the code correctly. Basically I want to `WorkerID` and `Workername` to come from the DLookUp from the UserID used to get the data here `GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username")`. I'm getting an object required error here:

```
"UPDATE CFRRR,attendance SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username") & ", assignedby = " & Forms!Supervisor!NavigationSubform!assignedby.Value & ", Dateassigned = #" & Now & "#, actiondate = #" & Now & "#, Workername = " & DLookup(attendance.username, "attendance", "username = UserID") & ", WorkerID = " & DLookup(attendance.userID, "attendance", "WorkerID = UserID") & " WHERE CFRRRID = " & rs!CFRRRID
```

Here's the full code for context:

```
 Set db = CurrentDb
    strSQL = "SELECT CFRRRID, [program], [language] FROM CFRRR WHERE assignedto Is Null"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    If Not rs.BOF And Not rs.EOF Then
        While Not rs.EOF

            strSQL = "UPDATE CFRRR,attendance SET assignedto = " & GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username") & ", assignedby = " & Forms!Supervisor!NavigationSubform!assignedby.Value & ", Dateassigned = #" & Now & "#, actiondate = #" & Now & "#, Workername = " & _
                              DLookup(attendance.username, "attendance", "username = UserID") & ", WorkerID = " & DLookup(attendance.userID, "attendance", "WorkerID = UserID") & " WHERE CFRRRID = " & rs!CFRRRID
            Debug.Print strSQL
            db.Execute strSQL, dbFailOnError
            rs.MoveNext
        Wend
    End If
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are the data types of `assignedto`, `assignedby`, `Workername`, `username `, `WorkerID`. Can you edit your post to include the method `GetNextAssignee`

Answer (score 0):

Your DLookup expressions are not correct.
The target field of the DLookup is a string-expression as well. So it should be:

```
... & DLookup("username", "attendance", "username = UserID") & ...
```

There are multiple occurances of this error in your SQL.

In addition to that, you should check the criteria expression as well:

```
..."username = UserID"...
```

That looks suspicious to me. But I can't tell if it is correct or not without knowing the table and data structure.

Comment: You may be right here ..."username = UserID"... because I was trying to say in the coding that username is derived from the UserID, so in the table attendance UserID is the primary key and `[username]` is just a field in `"attendance"`. The UserID would be essentially linked to the UserID, however I'm sure I didn't write that out correctly. Still learning SQL. Also when I made the changes you suggested I got a Data Type Mismatch in criteria expression. Thanks!

Comment: You should probably be using something like ... & DLookup("username", "attendance", "UserID = " & Me!FormControlWithUserId.Value ) & ... to achieve what you try to do here.

Comment: I actually got the answer somewhere else. I needed to change my code to `& DLookup("username", "attendance", "userID =  " & GetNextAssignee("program", "Language", "username"))` Thank you though.